# Значение сертификатов для заказчика

Tags: веб-программирование, работа

Какое значение для заказчика имеет наличие сертификатов по используемым в проекте технологиям? Речь идет о фрилансе.

Comment: спросите у заказчика. Только он знает.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В добавок к вышесказанному - если вы покажете сертификаты относящиеся к технологиям, с которыми Вам придётся работать, и к работе, которую Заказчик хочет Вам предложить - это будет плюс Вам в его глазах.

Хотя скорее всего он постарается этого не показать и заплатить меньше ;)

Но, в любом случае - они полезны. Хотя бы ради поднятия самооценки.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря какие сертификаты вы имеете ввиду. Оборудование, операционные системы, языки программирования и т.п.

Для рядового заказчика, почти никакого. Тут большую роль играют отзывы и проекты.
А вот в некоторых областях, то критично, имхо. Я бы не пустил работать с Cisco без сертификата.

Comment: Я имею ввиду сертификаты по веб-технологиям. Я так понял, наличие сертификатов критично в областях, связанных с системным администрированием?

Comment: Как по мне, да. Сертификаты лишний раз доказывают, что вы не просто исполните свою работу, а не порушите предыдущую, т.е. то, что вы отдаете себе отчет в том, что делаете. Думаю, что в веб-программировании примерно та же ситуация, на доработку проекта не возьмут абы кого. Но в силу того, что веб-приложение можно реально "пощупать" и посмотреть код, то часто ориентируются в этом случае на опыт предыдущих разработок.

Comment: По моим наблюдениям заказчик никогда этим не интересуется.
Но если требуется включиться в некий проект (который уже ведется) со специфическими технологиями, то вероятно сертификат может быть важен.

Comment: Да, да, и я о чем.